# my sql Database not updating from android app

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

I am new to *JSON* and android networking and I am trying to write code to update *mysql* database from android app using *PHP*. The database did update with the same code few hours ago, but now it doesn't. I don't understand why it is not updating now. I am using *wamp* server. 
I know I need to change url according to my computer's IP. I change it accordingly but the database doesn't update. I checked google, someone suggested to clear the cache of the web Browser. I did that too, but nothing happens.
Please help me. I am stuck!!

**Here is my code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressDialog progress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new SendRequest().execute();
}

public class SendRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute(){}

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://172.16.7.90/net.php");

            JSONObject postDataParams = new JSONObject();


            postDataParams.put("name", "saurav");
            postDataParams.put("email", "sau@gmail.com");

            Log.e("params", postDataParams.toString());

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
    if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
String line="";

while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

    sb.append(line);
    break;
}

in.close();
return sb.toString();

   }
    else {
    return new String("false : "+responseCode);
    }





        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    return "success";}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

 public String getPostDataString(JSONObject params) throws Exception {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;

    Iterator<String> itr = params.keys();

    while(itr.hasNext()){

        String key= itr.next();
        Object value = params.get(key);

        if (first){
            first = false};
        else{
            result.append("&")};

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(value.toString(), "UTF-8"));

    }
    return result.toString();
}
}
```

**Here is my net.php file:**

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$username='root';
$password='';
$database='database2';
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$dbc=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$database)or die('error');

$sql="INSERT INTO table1(first_name,email)" ."VALUES('$name','$email')";

$result=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>
```

Comment: Check if your wamp server is running or not

Comment: It is running. It shows green and I opened it in chrome. It opens

Comment: Than Check, if your request is coming to server or not. If request is coming than log or print your SQL query. Also try to use prepare statment to avoid SQL injection.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Did you know you can use **Retrofit**, **Gson** and etc for calling web services? They're really helpful :)

Comment: Check this link: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Comment: return something in your net.php and check what is the response from android studio console.